# Less works once only after save

Tags: css, less

I set up my php page to work with Less but Less works only one time after I save it. If I go to the page right after I save it, then less works. If I refresh it then less doesn't. Then I need to go back to less code save it again, then it works once more and same cycle goes over and over.

Why Less works only one time after I save it?

Here the link for the website:
http://goo.gl/3UM1ms

Comment: It is a bug in version 2.2.0, see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2381. Already fixed. Download the latest code and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason v2 works fine on my server but v2.2 doesn't. So I simply copied over v2's less js and it works fine.